# C# REST API taking application/xml not reading envelope when schema is present on the request

Tags: c#, xml, rest, soap

I'm trying to create a basic REST API which should take XML instead of JSON. The controller looks as following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using OEMTestFactoryREST.Models;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class VplController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("application/xml")]
    public IActionResult CreateOrder([FromBody] Envelope envelope)
    {
        if (envelope == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid data");
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

And Envelope.cs file as following:

```cs
[XmlType(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope")]
public class Envelope
{

}
```

I removed the properties inside to simplify the example.

When I run it through swagger and I run:

```xml
<Envelope>

</Envelope>
```

it works fine, however, when I use the XML as it's expected, from the client

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get this error:

```json
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-746f6559b87bd381a4f1ca98634d554b-e19eac5521a35ffe-00",
  "errors": {
    "": [
      "An error occurred while deserializing input data."
    ],
    "orderblabla": [
      "The orderblabla field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem is on the `soapenv` from the begin. Does anyone know how can I modify the controller/model, so it allows having `soapenv` on the beginning and end?

Comment: The issue is you are sending XML data that does not meet the schema.  Make sure you do a schema check before sending the xml.  There are lots of online schema checkers.  Here is one of them https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-validator

Comment: Try adding anyAttribute.  See : http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/xml/el_anyattribute.asp.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: @jdweng allright. Where shall I add the schema when I create it? as part of the namespace? Since I have no element inside Envelope, I guess the schema I'm not meeting is the one on the URL: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/. And that's indeed true, I don't have Header or Body, which are a part of the definition on that URL. Is there any way of auto-generating those elements to C#? So I generate the header and body as it's expected

Comment: The schema shows min for header being zero which is optional.  Body min is one so it is required.  So add a public class Body to your code and then add a public property to Envelope Body.  HTTP Post requires a body.  If you change to HTTP Get no body is required.  Don't get the request and response mixed up.  A request does not need a body with a Get, the soap response will have a body.

Comment: You are getting a 400 error which indicates the request is not formed correctly.  It could mean you are using POST and no body.  So change POST to GET.  The schema you posted is probably the response.  Does your request have an Envelope?

Comment: @jdweng It had to be post and the schema was for the request. I found the solution on another page where someone had almost a similar problem as I had. He posted the auto-generated code for envelope and body from that particular namespace (which I was unable to auto-generate myself). I just copied those clases into my project and it started working with some formatting. The page I used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/712472/c-parse-soap-response-for-elements-and-attribute-v
Thanks for helping!

Comment: You do not need a body.  Your body contains no useful info.  You could of change Post To Get and left the body blank.  The link you used is where the OP had an issue with parsing a Response.  Your issue is you are sending a bad request.  What you did works, but it is not the correct fix.  What you did was to do two things wrong and ended up getting the code to work.  It this case two wrongs make a right.